# How does one pass by pointers with two arguments in function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Can someone demonstrate how to pass by pointers using one function that takes two arguments from two variables as input?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int passPoints(int *x, int *y)
{
    int y = *x * *y;
    return(y);
}
int *X, *Y;
int main()
{
    cout<<"enter two values: ";
    cin>>*X;
    cin>>*Y;
    cout<<"RESULT = "<<passPoints(X,Y);
    return 0;
}
```

Having trouble.

Comment: X and Y are null pointers. Trying to input to what they point to is a bad idea.

Comment: what trouble? At least you need to tell us the trouble you are facing else no one knows what is your problem.

Comment: You need to change the local variable `int y` to `int z` or some such as currently it has a name conflict with the parameter `int* y`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
int X, Y;
int main()
{
    cout<<"enter two values: ";
    cin>>X;
    cin>>Y;
    cout<<"RESULT = "<<passPoints(&X,&Y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem in your code (if it is not a typo when you are extracting for question) is, int* X and Y are null pointer and the location they are pointing at are not valid for you to update.  You need to make sure that these pointers are pointing to a valid memory location, either by:

```
int x, y;
int* xPtr = &x;
int* yPtr = &y;
passPoints(xPtr, yPtr);
```

or simply

```
int x, y;
passPoints(&x, &y);
```

now the pointers received by `passPoints()` are valid pointers

Comment: They have static storage duration. They're null pointers, not uninitialized. Same consequences, though.

Comment: @chris good catch.  I always forgot in what situation variables is guaranteed to be initialized and when is not.  Therefore I always force myself to treat everything to be uninitialized and do proper initialization explicitly, which I believe is also a good practice :)

Comment: True, I've spent too much time learning intricacies, so I tend to find myself relying on them.

Comment: @chris I've had to use a compiler once that did not zero-initialize static variables unless you provided an initializer... it was very painful

Comment: @MattMcNabb, That sounds rather fun.